# Directory.Enumerate Files - need to filter by strict file extension

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code:

```
Dim File_Names_In_Path = Directory.EnumerateFiles(DropBox_Path, "*.csv")
```

which works fine on newer machines, however on a few older machines it's finding some files that the users have renamed to "*.csvo".

I'm aware of why this happens - with a wildcard and a three letter extension as per Microsoft's documentation.

I don't really have the option of making the users rename their old files.

How can I make the Directory.EnumerateFiles filter results to only pick .csv files?

I think it might be connected to using .where and the file extension but can't just figure how to add this to my code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to use the exact case of "csv" then

```
Dim File_Names_In_Path = Directory.EnumerateFiles(DropBox_Path, "*.csv").
                         Where(Function(f) Path.GetExtension(f) = ".csv")
```

or to make it case-insensitive:

```
Dim File_Names_In_Path = Directory.EnumerateFiles(DropBox_Path, "*.csv").
                         Where(Function(f) Path.GetExtension(f).Equals(".csv", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Note that the [`Path.GetExtension Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension) includes the dot at the start of the extension.